# Best HTML 5 video solution for mobile devices?

Tags: android, html5-video

I'm developing a mobile video platform and I have playing in mobile safari and some Android browsers. The problem I'm having is that my solutions thus far (have tried regular HTML 5 video as well as VideoJS) have only worked on about 50% of the Android browsers I've tested.

I have added the three web formats to my video tag (ogv, webm and mp4) as well as provided a fallback flash object but it seems that a lot of the Android mobile browsers still refuse to play any video.

Has anyone had a similar experience that could propose a solution?

Thanks,
  gearoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange resolution with this one. I need to add the video sources in the appropriate order to get multi-device compatability. The sources need to be added to the video tag in the following order:

1. MP4
2. WebM
3. OGV